# Show 'Automated Tasks' or 'Automation' in MIUI 14

Tags: android, security, miui

In MIUI 13 there was the possibility to show 'Automated Tasks' via the MIUI Security App what was a really helpful and nice feature. Unfortunately, on MIUI 14 the Security App looks quite different and up to now I was not able to find where to open 'Automated Tasks'. Can somebody help me out here?

Thanks!

I tried to install a older version of the Security App what failed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.